Allow Content-Security-Policy frame-ancestors by origin in Apache
I want to allow iframe for site only on a specific sites
I cat to make this:
Header set Content-Security-Policy "frame-ancestors 'self' http://myorigin.com"

But it will be shown in browser response header.
I try to hide it from headers:
<If "%{HTTP_HOST} != 'myorigin.com'">
    Header set Content-Security-Policy "frame-ancestors 'self'"
</If>

But it's not working
Can someone help please?
